# Should I use dynamic import for my entire app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I have a `React` app and my `bundle` getting bigger and bigger.

-Should i use `dynamic import` (`React.lazy`) for entire my app?

-Can i use one `React.Suspense` (It will surround the `App` tag) for entire my app?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 3):

- You can split yout app into multiple SPAs, each with it own smaller bundle.
- Perform bundle minification in production build - this can be done without any impact on your ability to debug the bundle.
- Separate the dependencies (including React library) into a separate bundle and ensure it doesn't need to be reloaded when client switches from one SPA to another.

[crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) is a boilerplate project that demonstrates all these techniques.

P.S.
Using dynamic imports is beneficial when, for example, the Reporting SPA consists of 10 reporting components and you know the `Component7` will be used by few people and/or infrequently. Then it's a good candidate for dynamic import.